# How do I get all of the user profile fields?

Tags: development, user-profile

How do I get all fields from user profiles including quote and tags? I'm using C#.

Answer (score 2):

User Profile data is pretty easy to work with.

You can access it through the API by using the UserProfileManager and the GetUserProfile method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.aspx

You can also access it through the web services which opens it up to non-SharePoint Apps, InfoPath forms, etc.  UserProfileService.asmx - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms550407.aspx

Here is a link for the SocialData namespace with info on how to work with tags and notes.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426882.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I want to access specific field (QUOTE) from profile database. but it is not available by default. the quote is popup menu next to image in the my profile page. any advice.

Comment: The field is called "Status Message" and the internal identifier is "SPS-StatusNotes".  Here is a post I wrote about it.  http://nextconnect.blogspot.com/2010/09/disabling-whats-happening-display-on.html